# How can I distinguish whether my onDataChanged was triggered by handheld or wear?

Tags: wear-os, google-data-api, android-wear-data-api

How can I distinguish whether my data was edited on my handheld or on my wear?

According to the docs:

You can listen for the following events with WearableListenerService:

```
onDataChanged() - Called when data item objects are created, changed, 
or deleted. An event on one side of a connection 
triggers this callback on both sides.
```

I'm using the service, but want to ignore the items, if they are edited on the handheld, and only want

Comment: Can you give a use case for this? If changes made by the mobile are not important, why would you allow the mobile device make any changes to begin with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the NodeApi.getLocalNode():

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/NodeApi